# Xamarin ListView Grouping Issue

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, grouping

I am having trouble with grouping using a ListView in Xamarin. I have looked at more guides than I can count, but I'm still not able to get it working. I can see that the ViewModel property is being set properly, but all I get is a blank screen. Please don't answer with a link to another guide, as I have probably already looked at it and it did not help. I believe I am very close.

Class Domain:

```
public class TechInventoryDetail
{
    public int EquipmentInventoryDetailEntityId { get; set; }

    public int TechId { get; set; }

    public string CodeDetail { get; set; }

    public string CodeDescription { get; set; }

    public int Need { get; set; }

    public int Have { get; set; }

    public string ServiceCategory { get; set; }
}
```

View Model Property:

```
private ObservableRangeCollection<Models.Grouping<string, TechInventoryDetail>> _techEquipmentOverview = new ObservableRangeCollection<Models.Grouping<string, TechInventoryDetail>>();

public ObservableRangeCollection<Models.Grouping<string, TechInventoryDetail>> TechEquipmentOverview
{
    get => _techEquipmentOverview;
    set { _techEquipmentOverview = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
}
```

Set Using View Model Method:

```
public async Task GetTechEquipmentOverviewAsync()
{
    var result = await _techService.GetTechEquipmentOverviewAsync(false);

    if (result.Success)
    {
        var equipmentGrouped = result.Data.InventoryDetail.GroupBy(c => c.ServiceCategory, c => c);
        var groups = equipmentGrouped.Select(g => new Models.Grouping<string, TechInventoryDetail>(g.Key, g)).ToList();

        if (groups.Any())
        {
            TechEquipmentOverview = new ObservableRangeCollection<Models.Grouping<string, TechInventoryDetail>>();
            TechEquipmentOverview.AddRange(groups);
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml ListView:

```
<ListView HasUnevenRows="true" 
              IsGroupingEnabled="true"
              GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding TechEquipmentOverview}">
        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout Padding="0,5,0,5" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                Style="{StaticResource EquipmentGroupHeader}"
                                Text="{Binding Key}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Padding="5">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.Children>
                            <Label
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                Style="{StaticResource DefaultSectionHeader}"
                                Text="{Binding CodeDetail}" />

                            <Label
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Margin="0,5,5,5"
                                Style="{StaticResource H1}"
                                Text="Need" />
                            <Label
                                Grid.Row="2"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Margin="0,15,5,5"
                                LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                Style="{StaticResource H2}"
                                Text="{Binding Need}" />

                            <Label
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Margin="0,5,5,5"
                                Style="{StaticResource H1}"
                                Text="Have" />
                            <Label
                                Grid.Row="2"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Margin="0,15,5,5"
                                LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                Style="{StaticResource H2}"
                                Text="{Binding Have}" />
                        </Grid.Children>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your class TechInventoryDetail needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `GetTechEquipmentOverviewAsync` method, you are resetting the `TechEquipmentOverview` observable collection and the **UI** doesn't know about the new list.

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your ViewModel and **notify** the UI that the list reference has changed. Also, make sure you are notifying the UI on the main UI thread by using `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`.

Comment: I have changed my ViewModel property to do as you suggested. It seems to work, but I have to refresh the page in order for anything to show up. I'm sure this has to do with your last sentence, but I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: There is a main UI thread that **UI** elements like to be updated on. `ListViews` almost require you to be on the UI thread when updating the list. `iOS` and sometimes `Android` will even exception if not updated on the main UI thread. Using `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` will run an **action** on the main thread allowing the UI to update correctly. Hope this helps

Comment: I guess he only needs to instantiate the `TechEquipmentOverview` list at the constructor, and when calling `GetTechEquipmentOverviewAsync` just `Clear` it.

Comment: About the Main UI thing: just change your `AddRange` code to: `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => TechEquipmentOverview.AddRange(groups));`